# Cannot find any hard drive after Vaio BIOS upgrade

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios, sony-vaio, efi

So the thing is that I just **upgraded BIOS version** with official Sony Vaio Tool, but after it got upgraded **the laptop cannot find any hard drive**.

- I'm using a **Sony Vaio SVF1531A4E with the main HDD and secondary SSD in optical bay (using adapter)**.
- Windows was installed on SSD drive before the errror.
- Initially it returned me `error 0xc0000185` with missing or corrupted files: `winload.efi` , `\Windows\system32\config\system`

I tried resetting EFI FAT32 partition via Recovery Console, reinstalling in SSD, trying to install Linux and pressing power button for 30s and stuff, but none of them worked.

Currently, both disks are completely wiped and I'm installing Windows 8 in main HDD and it seems to work but it's going really slow. If this doesn't work, **what should I do?**

Comment: You updated the BIOS, which may have (sounds like it) included resetting it to the factory defaults.  This probably changed the mode of the hard drive controller, and/or secure boot, etc. requiring Windows to be reinstalled.  Next time take notes of the BIOS settings before updating the BIOS.  As-is, "if this doesn't work what should I do" is not an actual problem we can help you with. So, come back when you have an actual problem you are trying to solve and we'll see what we can do.  Until then, just keep on keeping on. :)  VTC.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ok, I note it! Somehow I solved it switching the SSD bay with the HDD bay and installing Windows in the main (SSD). Even so, I still don't know how to solve the previous error  :(